# C ++ custom delete operator does not work well?

Tags: c++, virtual, delete-operator

First of all to say that I am Spanish and my English is really bad, I used a translator with what I apologize for looking like an illiterate :)

---

I have not played c ++ for years and I have forgotten so much that maybe the doubt I have or the possible failure is really something basic in the language.

I have written a small code to test the overhead of the delete operator in c ++ with a virtual destructor and I have found that it only works correctly the first time that delete is called.

The code is here (it's a page that allows you to write code online and execute it, I've tested it in visual studio and gcc and it's exactly the same): https://onlinegdb.com/SkiI1dNDQ

Could someone tell me why this is happening? Only the first time works well and the second one is not going well

I put the code here also and the result it gives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { printf("~Base\r\n"); }
    void operator delete(void *m) { printf("delete Base\r\n"); }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() { x = 1; }
    ~Derived() { printf("~Derived\r\n"); }
    void operator delete(void *m) { printf("delete Derived\r\n"); }
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Derived *derived = new Derived();
    printf("1) delete derived (%i)\r\n", ((Derived*)derived)->x);
    delete derived;
    printf("2) delete derived (%i)\r\n", ((Derived*)derived)->x);
    delete derived;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1) delete derived (1)
~Derived
~Base
delete Derived
2) delete derived (1)
~Base
delete Base
```

Now, if we remove the "virtual" class called "Base" everything is perfect, logically whenever we call the delete with "Derived" (the code is ready to remove the virtual and nothing fails). To execute it: https://onlinegdb.com/SkXkgdVP7

Thanks

Comment: delete twice the same non null pointer is Undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: You are `delete`ing `derived` twice. Don't do that.

Comment: `derived->x` is also UB once deleted.

Comment: You are deleting an already deleted object.

Comment: You cannot eat what has already been consumed....wait...there is a movie for that.

Comment: What you're overlooking is that `delete derived` does more than just call `Derived::operator delete()`.  It also runs the destructor.  (Your debug output clearly shows this.)  Even though your `operator delete()` implementation doesn't make the memory inaccessible, doing anything further with `derived` is forbidden because its destructor has already run.

Comment: Indeed the problem was that, once called the destructor, the virtual table seems to stop working and does not take into account the class hierarchy. I have made a test code to verify it and that happens with an explicit call to the destructor: https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkHVK9EwX
Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

```
Derived *derived = new Derived();
printf("1) delete derived (%i)\r\n", ((Derived*)derived)->x);
delete derived;
printf("2) delete derived (%i)\r\n", ((Derived*)derived)->x);
delete derived;
```

The above code is incorrect, and is invoking undefined behavior.  You can only delete an object once; above you are (attempting to) delete the same object twice.  The problem is that after the first call to delete, `derived` is now a dangling pointer (i.e. it's not pointing to a valid object anymore) and it's an error to try to dereference it in any way (including calling `delete` on it).

Comment: To be picky, `delete` is not a dereference operation. The standard explicitly says that deleting such a pointer is UB (with no diagnostic required)

Comment: So even if the delete operator is overloaded and the memory is not released, nobody assures us that this object will continue to exist?